# How to make the code synchronous without using timeout in React-Redux middleware

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to dispatch an action and using middleware to check if token expired and if expired I am generating new token. I am then using this new token in api. The problem is the code is flowing asynchronously. The api is using old token instead of the generated new token. Please help me resolve the issue.
Note - middleware code is in index.js file

```
this.props.checkToken(oldToken) //action dispatched goes to middleware
apicall(window.sessionSTorage.getItem('token')) //api using token

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
      checkToken: (token) => dispatch (actionCreators.checkToken(token))
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(myComponent)
```

Action Creator -

```
export const checkToken = (token) => {
return {
    type: actionTypes.checkToken,
    token: token,
}}
```

MIddleware -

```
//Middleware code here
const logger = store => {
    return next => {
        return action => {
            if (tokenExpired) {
                fetch (url, {
                   method: 'POST',
                   body: JSON.stringify(refresh),
                   headers: {
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                   }
                })
                .then ((response) => response.json())
                .then ((findresponse) => {
                     window.sessionStorage.setItem('token', findresponse.token);
                })
            }

            return next(action);
       }
   }}
```

Comment: generatenewToken is asynchronious?

Comment: generatenewToken is synchronous.

Comment: I see, you call apicall immediately after you dispatch the action, you should use .then or async/await on this.props.checkToken(oldToken)

Comment: the question is why do you need to have action this.props.checkToken(oldToken), since you update token in middleware anyways?

Comment: First, promises work only for functions if i'm not wrong? because i've tried .then and async/await but they not working. Second, I'm refreshing my token just before any api calls that's why i'm using that action. Third, i'm new to middleware so right now i'm understanding it :)

Comment: add code to your post how you define action and how you making it available in the component props

Comment: I hope this much code is okay

Comment: accordingly to your code, action will be called synchronously, probably you have problem somewhere else, try to debug it properly

Comment: After debugging I found that when I call my refresh token api, it is not waiting for the response and starts executing apicall line which is not expected. I have made some modifications in my code.

Comment: move next() function inside the promise

Answer (score 0):

Action will return promise so you can do `apicall` on successful completion of the promise

```
this.props.checkToken(oldToken).then(()=>apicall(window.sessionSTorage.getItem('token'))
```

or using async/await

```
await this.props.checkToken(oldToken) //action dispatched goes to middleware
apicall(window.sessionSTorage.getItem('token')) //api using token
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are many solutions for your question(edit the middleware or using RXJS subscription or create another middle-ware to handle token... ) but I don't think this is a good practice. This is because we don't need to dispatch an action to `checktoken`.

It should be done by the `request` middleware which runs before every requests or when the location path be changed. Your solution also leads to the difficulties to refresh the token and re-call the existing requests with the new one.

Comment: this is a good example(https://codesandbox.io/s/m5n2xjl6pj). You can edit `appFetch` to get your desire